# using requests and beautiful soup to login to asp website

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write a program that will log into an asp website. Every time i run the program it gives me this error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/icecreamlolcat/python/2.py", line 17, in <module>
    EVENTVALIDATION=soup.find(id="__EVENTVALIDATION")['value']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL="website"
headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36"}

username="username"
password="password"

s=requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)
r=s.get(URL)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content)

VIEWSTATE=soup.find(id="__VIEWSTATE")['value']
VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=soup.find(id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR")['value']
EVENTVALIDATION=soup.find(id="__EVENTVALIDATION")['value']

login_data={"__VIEWSTATE":VIEWSTATE,
"__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR":VIEWSTATEGENERATOR,
"__EVENTVALIDATION":EVENTVALIDATION,
"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderNavPane$LeftSection$UserLogin$UserName":username,
"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderNavPane$LeftSection$UserLogin$Password":password,
"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderNavPane$LeftSection$UserLogin$LoginButton":"Log In"}

r=s.post(URL, data=login_data)
print r.url
```

Comment: From the error message, it tells that soup.find(id="__EVENTVALIDATION") = None, meaning that it cannot find the element. Your id value might be incorrect.

Comment: You may want to look at using selenium. Just an easier solution in my opinion